# Are temp sensors for Ryzen CPUs inaccurate?

Tags: ubuntu, amd, sensors

I have a Ryzen 3950X cpu.

In the Asus Bios, I sent the fans to spin at 100% RPM at a temperature of 70C. However, they definitely don't spin at 100% RPM at 70C. The temperature needs to reach 75C-80C before they reach 100%

From looking at Google, this might be because running `sensors` on Linux is not as accurate as using "Ryzen Master" on Windows.

Are they any good Linux substitutes?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard reports of incorrect temperature readings by the k10temp driver in Linux. Please try installing a trial Windows version, e.g. Windows 10 Enterprise, run HWiINFO4 in it and see if anything's different.

The only alternative to the k10temp driver is https://github.com/ocerman/zenpower but it should provide the same temperature readings. Compile it, `rmmod k10temp`, `insmod zenpower.ko` and see for yourself, `sensors`.